# Language sometimes change into Language System in My Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, localization, locale

I face some Language bugs. I Hope someone can help

So there is sometime my activity recreate itself when the app is idle (the duration is random). After the activity recreated, the language on the app (in this case "in") change to system language ("en")

But, when i debug the app. Currently locale is "in" not "en"

How is that possible ?
Is there a way to force not use System Language at all ?
I really confused. Hope someone can reach me out

Comment: try to designate the locale each time the activity is recreated

Comment: Already did but same result
Currently Locale is "in" but the app language is in english